# Create a batch file that displays a message box (Windows 10)

Tags: batch-file

I’m creating a batch program and I want a popup message to be displayed if there is an error. Previous posts have had answers that say msg * “Your message here” is the way to do it, however this apparently doesn’t work under Windows 10 as the annoying “Msg is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file” error message is displayed.

Comment: `>NUL powershell "(new-object -COM WScript.Shell).popup('Your message here.')"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to do it you just make a vbs file containing:

```
x=msgbox("Your Text Here",0, "Your Title Here")
```

and the in your batch file you do:

```
call vbs.vbs
```

it works for me

Comment: Is there a difference between start and call? I’ve always used start when opening files in batch.

Comment: @GypsyGypsy yes there is, let's say you have to batch files the one is the menu and the other is where you have open ftp, if you start the ftp.bat a new window will open, but call will just do what the ftp.bat has inside of it

Comment: So it’s kinda like opening a new window in Firefox, but you’re just opening a new tab rather than an entirely new window?

Comment: ya kinda. but instead of opening a new tab you are actually getting the old tab to do what the new tab would have done and then if you make go to start it's like going back to what the old tab would do

Comment: @rojo's solution is preferable as it doesn't need an additional (temporary) file `>NUL powershell "(new-object -COM WScript.Shell).popup('Your message here.',0,'Window title')"`  BTW Call is **only** needed to run another batch AND return.

Comment: Thanks @HackerNCoder I’ll try it. <aside>@rojo I said batch, not PowerShell. I no a lot more about batch than PS (I even know how to have batch files be compiled down to machine code (executable) files) but your help is highly appreciated anyway :)</aside>

Comment: @GypsyGypsy actually you can just paste the PS code into your batch file and it will run!

Comment: @LotPings do you need the >nulpowershell bit at the start or is that just part of the PS prompt?

Comment: It suppresses Powershell's return of `1` resp `-1` if run with a delay other than 0 and it times out.

Comment: I tried PS but it didn’t work as intended, so I’m gunna go down the VBS road as @HackerNCoder suggested. Another reason for this is that I want my program to work with Windows versions lower than 7; I believe that all Windows systems should be regarded, even ones that aren’t supported by Microsoft anymore.